# Building a table

Tags: list-manipulation

I am having trouble building a table that looks similar to this:
With the values of A = 1, δ = 0.05, α = 0.33, K0 = 1, and St is a random number between 0,1. T-1 means the previous period.

[image]

I have written the following code:

```
 With[{A = 1., \[Delta] = 0.05, \[Alpha] = 0.33}, 
  NestList[Apply[
    Function[{k, y, c, s, i}, 
     With[{st = RandomReal[]}, {(1 - \[Delta]) k + 
        i, (k^\[Alpha] *A^(1 - \[Alpha])), st, (1 - s) y, s y}]]], 
   With[{st = RandomReal[]}, {1., 1., 1 - st, st, st}], 4]]]
```

My issue is that when I use the formulas to check if the output I find the they are not correct.
I need some help on how to solve this issue, or if there is an easier way to do this.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Define the display format for indexed variables

```
(Format[#[t_]] := Subscript[#, t]) & /@ {k, i, y, s, c};
```

`k` is the only variable defined by a recurrence

```
k[0] = 1;
k[t_] := k[t] = (1 - δ) k[t - 1] + i[t - 1];
```

To reproduce the given results, the random values (`s[t]`) must be specified.

```
Evaluate[Array[s, 5, 0]] = {0.34, 0.95, 0.64, 0.42, 0.02};

y[t_] := k[t]^α a^(1 - α);
c[t_] := (1 - s[t]) y[t];
i[t_] := s[t] y[t]

a = 1; δ = 1/20; α = 33/100;

header = {t,
   StringForm["``", HoldForm[k[t] = (1 - δ) k["t-1"] + i["t-1"]]],
   StringForm["``", HoldForm[y[t] = k[t]^α a^(1 - α)]],
   s[t], StringForm["``", HoldForm[c[t] = (1 - s[t]) y[t]]],
   StringForm["``", HoldForm[i[t] = s[t] y[t]]]};

Join[{header}, Table[{t, k[t], y[t], s[t], c[t], i[t]}, {t, 0, 4}]] // 
  Grid[#, Dividers -> {Center, {2 -> True, 7 -> True}}] & // 
 NumberForm[#, {5, 2}] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So to create a similar table but with actual random numbers I need to define ```s[t_]=RandomReal[]```?

Comment: Yes that would work

Comment: When I define s[t_]=RandomReal[] the random number stays the same throughout. Is there a way to have different St at different T?

Comment: Use SetDelayed := rather than Set =

Comment: Amazing thank you very much kind sir :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
SeedRandom[1];
T = 4;
A = 1;
\[Delta] = 0.05;
\[Alpha] = 0.33;
k[0] = 1;
r := RandomReal[{0, 1}]
```

Equations:

```
y[0] = 1;
k[t_] := k[t] = (1 - \[Delta]) k[t - 1] + i[t - 1]
c[t_] := c[t] = (1 - sT[t]) y[t]
i[t_] := i[t] = sT[t] y[t]
y[t_] := y[t] = (k[t]^\[Alpha] A^(1 - \[Alpha]))
sT[t_] := sT[t] = r
```

Use the following, if you want to replicate the table in the OP (after disabling the corresponding code line above)

> (* sT[0]=0.34;sT[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK0nU.png)=0.95; sT[2]=0.64; sT[3]=0.42; sT[4]=0.02; *)

Generating data:

```
data = Table[{t, k[t], y[t], sT[t], c[t], i[t]}, {t, 0, 4}]
```

Visualizing:

```
Grid[Prepend[ 
  MapAt[Style[NumberForm[#, {5, 2}], 14, "BookAntiqua"] &, 
   data, {All, All}]
  , TraditionalForm /@ {"t", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(K\), \
\(t\)]\)=(1-\[Delta])\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(K\), \(t - \
1\)]\)+\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(t - 1\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Y\), \(t\)]\)=(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(K\), \
\(t\)]\)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\), \
\(\[Alpha]\)]\)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(A\), \(1 - \[Alpha]\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \(t\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(C\), \(t\)]\)=(1-\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \
\(t\)]\))\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Y\), \(t\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(t\)]\)=\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \(t\
\)]\)\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Y\), \(t\)]\)"}]
 , Dividers -> {
   {False, {True}, False}
   , {False, True, {False}, True}
   }
 , Alignment -> {{Center, {Center}}, {Center, Center}}
 , Spacings -> {{1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3}, 1}
 ]
```

[image]